# Javascript: Escaping quotes from dynamic content

Tags: javascript, escaping, double-quotes

I've got a var which takes a string returned by the Facebook API and turns it into a JSON object. Inside the object there is a title of Fan Pages.

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonString; ?>');
```

The part of string returned by FB of concern looks something like this:

```
{"data":[
    {"category":"Website",
    "name":"Page's Title",
    "access_token":"TOKEN"}
]}
```

I'm wrapping the `<?php echo $jsonString; ?>` in single quotes because if I used double quotes they'd clash with the double quotes inside the string returned by FB. However see the single quote inside `Page's Title`? If it happens that FB returns a string that contains a single quote that breaks my JS code and I get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in my console.

How can I make my code robust enough to parse the string while allowing for the double quotes inside it and the possibility of single quotes also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `addslashes()`, Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted. These characters are single quote (`'`), double quote (`"`), backslash (`\`) and NUL (the NULL byte).

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse('<?php echo addslashes($jsonString); ?>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [addslashes()](https://www.php.net/addslashes)

This will return a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted.

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse('<?php echo addslashes($jsonString); ?>');
```